# Can I use class scope like a namespace instead of prefixing everything with the class name

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

So inside header files I can do

```
namespace X {
    doThis();
}
```

and in the implementation file I can do

```
namespace X {
   doThis() { .... }
}
```

But if I have a class

```
class X {
    public:
    doThis();
};
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this in the implementation file

```
class X {
    doThis() { .... }
}
```

instead of `X::doThis() { .... }`?

Comment: No is the short answer. A namespace can be split into several pieces, a class definition must appear as a single piece (although individual items within the class maybe defined outside of the class).

Comment: Because I need a separate .cpp file so I can set the static variables

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @john Well, for example if theres many static variables, or many methods, it would look ugly to have MyClass:: infront of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the "Java hack"¹, where you "inherit" from the class to get its members into your namespace:

```
class MyUserType : /*protected|private*/ X {

     void foo() {
         doThis(); // works
     }
}
```

Of course this only works of

- the class doesn't define additional (non-static) features that interfere when inherited
- your calling code is in a class that can inherit from the type
- the derived class is not a template because 2-phase lookup makes things weird again (though you can use `using` declarations to mitigate them, on a name-by-name basis)

---

#### Re: static data members/out of class definition

In the comments you seem to have a problem with brevity of code mostly. Look into

> Disclaimer: following examples largely copied from cppreference

1. [`inline` variables (c++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), which is about namespace level static variables, which also applies to class members:

   [image]

- constexpr/const static member initialization right in the declaration.

  If a static data member of integral or enumeration type is declared const (and not volatile), it can be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition:

  ```
   struct X
   {
       const static int n = 1;
       const static int m{2}; // since C++11
       const static int k;
   };
   const int X::k = 3;
  ```

0. constexpr members are even required to have the initializer in the declaration:

   ```
   struct X {
       constexpr static int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };        // OK
       constexpr static std::complex<double> n = {1,2}; // OK
       constexpr static int k; // Error: constexpr static requires an initializer
   };
   ```
1. Note that in some circumstances you may still need out-of-class definitions, but without the initializer:

   If a const non-inline (since C++17) static data member or a constexpr static data member (since C++11)(until C++17²) is [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use), a definition at namespace scope is still required, but it cannot have an initializer. A definition may be provided even though redundant (since C++17).

   ```
   struct X {
       static const int n = 1;
       static constexpr int m = 4;
   };
   const int *p = &X::n, *q = &X::m; // X::n and X::m are odr-used
   const int X::n;             // … so a definition is necessary
   constexpr int X::m;         // … (except for X::m in C++17)
   ```

---

¹ for the longest time Java didn't have enumerations, so you'd define static constants in a base class an "inherit" from it to get the constants.

²     If a static data member is declared constexpr, it is implicitly inline and does not need to be redeclared at namespace scope. This redeclaration without an initializer (formerly required as shown above) is still permitted, but is deprecated.